# Embedded Youtube video Full Screen Works with Firefox But Not Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, youtube

So I have a problem with using an embedded youtube video.

Here is my iframe code

`<iframe width="560" height="370" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PrTXCPex_3o" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="2"></iframe>`

As you can see, I am using allowfullscreen, in fact, it works perfectly fine for Firefox. However, when I try it with chrome, it just sends me to the top of the page and freezes up there until I hit the escape key. It is almost like hitting fullscreen is making the browser go fullscreen (Like hitting F11 In windows) instead of the video.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a live test website of my project so you guys can test it yourself with multiple browsers.

http://tech-solutions-llc.com

Thanks again!